# Windows 7 Blue Screen 0x000000f7

Tags: windows-7, firefox, drivers, bsod, malware

Earlier this evening my computer crashed while browsing the web. I had three Firefox tabs open, on YouTube, Soundcloud, and PCGamer. While on PCGamer, the screen froze, and the sound replayed a small section repeatedly before crashing to blue screen with the following error:

0x000000f7 (0xfffff8800ae22ae8, 0x0000f960002e992f, 0xffff069fffd166d0, 0x0000000000000000).

From my research, this is a "A driver has overrun a stack-based buffer. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain access to gain control of this machine."

It has only happened once, which could mean nothing, however this is still concerning to me, as I don't believe I have any malware or viruses. A Malwarebytes Anti-Malware scan found nothing, and a Spybot scan is currently running. I also run AVG 2015 as my primary defense. I will be performing a safemode scan later this evening once Spybot's results come in, but I wanted to ask Superuser in case this is a more serious issue that I should be concerned with.

I have a DMP file, however it is over 900MB in size. I can zip and upload this to dropbox if needed/requested.

I appreciate any help/insight into this issue.

Comment: In general you'll need to determine which driver it was and try updating/changing the driver. If it keeps happening, consider replacing the hardware its related to. If your question is "should I be concerned?" we can't answer that based on this info -- yes it could be a "one-off", or not. :)

Comment: If your question is "How do I find out which driver?" consider questions like [How should I approach analysing this Windows crash dump?](http://superuser.com/questions/58245/how-should-i-approach-analysing-this-windows-crash-dump?rq=1), [How can I read a dmp file in windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/565358/how-can-i-read-a-dmp-file-in-windows-7), [Reasons for the blue screen of death in Windows 7 logs](http://superuser.com/questions/359446/reasons-for-the-blue-screen-of-death-in-windows-7-logs), etc.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Using BlueScreenView, it would seem the faulting drivers were "win32k.sys" and "ntoskrnl.exe". All virus scans have come back empty, and AdwCleaner found some files but nothing that seemed major. I'm sorry, I'm just not sure what to make of it. I haven't changed any drivers recently, and in fact the only recent thing that was done was Windows automatic updates from early this morning.

Comment: Bug Check 0xF7: DRIVER_OVERRAN_STACK_BUFFER: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Copy the dmp to a different PC and analyze it with Windbg: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

Comment: @magicandre1981 I tried to follow along on the video but I've never used the Windows Debugging Tool before, and I'm really not sure what I'm looking for. Would it be alright to send it to you?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have sent you an email. Thanks.

Comment: the dump is corrupted (CORRUPT_MODULELIST) so I can't debug it. Test your hardware (RAM, HDD, CPU) for errors.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I will test those things when I get home. Should I be worried about malware/a virus/hijacking on my machine? My scans hadn't found anything but in the back of my mind I'm definitely worried about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new dump also shows hardware issues. Here the [Instruction Pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) is MISALIGNED.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_OVERRAN_STACK_BUFFER (f7)
A driver has overrun a stack-based buffer.  This overrun could potentially
allow a malicious user to gain control of this machine.
DESCRIPTION
A driver overran a stack-based buffer (or local variable) in a way that would
have overwritten the function's return address and jumped back to an arbitrary
address when the function returned.  This is the classic "buffer overrun"
hacking attack and the system has been brought down to prevent a malicious user
from gaining complete control of it.
Do a kb to get a stack backtrace -- the last routine on the stack before the
buffer overrun handlers and bugcheck call is the one that overran its local
variable(s).
Arguments:
Arg1: 000000000e728077, Actual security check cookie from the stack
Arg2: 0000f960003387ed, Expected security check cookie
Arg3: ffff069fffcc7812, Complement of the expected security check cookie
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero

Debugging Details:
------------------


BIOS_DATE:  02/24/2009

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  EP45T-UD3LR

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  x.x

BUGCHECK_P1: e728077

BUGCHECK_P2: f960003387ed

BUGCHECK_P3: ffff069fffcc7812

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

SECURITY_COOKIE:  Expected 0000f960003387ed found 000000000e728077

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: 91d

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 17

CPU_STEPPING: a

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xF7

PROCESS_NAME:  Audiosurf2.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10069.9 amd64fre

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  fffff8800b5a6198 -- (.exr 0xfffff8800b5a6198)
ExceptionAddress: fffff96000113c70 (win32k!SfnINLPCREATESTRUCT+0x0000000000000678)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000


STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 win32k!_report_gsfailure
02 win32k!_GSHandlerCheck_SEH
03 nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
04 nt!RtlDispatchException
05 nt!KiDispatchException
06 nt!KiExceptionDispatch
07 nt!KiPageFault
08 win32k!SfnINLPCREATESTRUCT
09 0x0
0a 0x0
0b 0x0
0c 0x0
0d 0x0
0e 0x0
0f 0x0
10 dxgkrnl!DxgkPresent
11 win32k!NtGdiDdDDIPresent
12 nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd


SYMBOL_NAME:  dxgkrnl!DxgkPresent+543

MODULE_NAME: hardware

BUCKET_ID:  X64_IP_MISALIGNED

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  X64_IP_MISALIGNED
```

So, test your RAM for errors with [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso) and stress / torture test your CPU with [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/download/).

Also try to update the BIOS to Version F12E. You still use BIOS F5.

Comment: Memtest has run with one pass, no errors. Prime95 has been going for about 30 minutes now with all tests passing so far. Could this be a mobo issue? Is it anything to do with graphics card drivers?

Comment: run memtest more times. Also run Prime95 for 4-5 hours. Also post pictures of the memory and SPD tabs from CPU-Z:http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: ![Memory Tab](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1555462/memory.PNG)

![SPD Tab](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1555462/spd.PNG)

Comment: Memtest ran two passes and did not find any errors. I will let Prime95 run again later today, but I don't know if I will leave it for 4-5 hours. 1 at the most.

Comment: I have run Prime95 for 1 hour on Small test, 1 hour on In-Place, and 1 hour on Blend. No errors detected.

Comment: try the BIOS update and look if this improves stability.

Comment: does the new BIOS improve the stability and fix the issue?

Comment: Well, I haven't done the BIOS update, I'm waiting on my brother to help me identify what revision mobo I have. In the meantime, downgrading my graphics driver further has helped, no crashes in a week now.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Bios was flashed to newest version, start up time is a bit better so that's cool. No crashes, but I think it was more to do with faulty nvidia drivers. Thanks for the help @magicandre1981